# How can show thankyou after onsubmit the post method form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, submit

My code:

```
<html> <body>
 
<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts sometext.</p>
 
<form id="abc" action="https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php"
onsubmit="myFunction()">   Enter name: <input type="text"
name="fname">   <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>
 
<script> function myFunction() {
     alert("The form was submitted"); } </script>
 
</body> </html>
```

It run ok, but i want after submit will show thankyou change form id, don't alert, it display text "thank you" like picture: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5fPt.png)

My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nguoicovan/adpjq8bc/

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax Jquery

```
<html> <body>

<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts sometext.</p>

<form id="abc" action="https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php"
onsubmit="myFunction()">   Enter name: <input type="text"
name="fname">   <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>

<script> function myFunction() {
     alert("The form was submitted"); } </script>

</body>
<script> $("#abc").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.get("https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php",$("#abc").serialize(),function(data){alert("Thank you for submitting ")})
})</script> </html>
```

don't forget to include jquery before you use it

Comment: can you test on jsfiddle ?, code don't run :( and it don't show thankyou text when submit form

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="app">
<p>When you submit the form, a function is triggered which alerts some text.</p>

    <form id="abc" action="https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php">
      Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $('form#abc').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("form#abc").serializeArray();
        console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({
          url: "https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          crossDomain: true,
          success:function(json){
            $('#app').html('<h1>Thank You</h1>');   
          },
          error:function(){
            $('#app').html('<h1>Thank You</h1>');   
          }  
        });
    });     
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i run your code, result is error:function. You change text "thank you" to "error" to view result

Comment: Yes It will because `https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php` not returns `jsonp` data. I assumed yours url will be different and it will return `json` or `jsonp` data.

Comment: i change data to "json" but still error, but when don't use ajax, the code run ok, how i can show thankyou after submit ?

Comment: then its CROS issue. If you have access to the `action url`  code, return the data as `jsonp` otherwise you have to enable CROS on that server. Set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-frontend.com`

Answer (score -1):

You can change your "action" to your thank you page

```
<form action="thankyou.php">
```

So that when you trigger the the submit button it will go to thankyou.php you can do also your backend functionality on that page.